# Agrupar Dados com Preferência-MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou tentando agrupar linhas iguais, mas baseado em um valor.
Eu sei que é possível através de uma `sub-query`, porém como estou usando `inner join` não consegui aplicar.

```
 SELECT * FROM Concessionarias C inner join Concessionarias_Marcas CM on  
 C.id = CM.Concessionarias_id and C.Estados_id = 14 group by C.id order by 
 (Marcas_id = 31) DESC;
```

Esta Query retorna a seguinte informação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do BD :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Problema:

Quando eu coloco para agrupar, ele agrupa corretamente, porém queria que ao agrupar, agrupasse o item que está com  (Marcas_id = 31).

Como tenho 2 linhas repetidas, ao agrupar, ele escolheria a linha onde Marcas_id é igual a 31.
Neste caso, ele está escolhendo (Marcas_id = 12)

Como eu poderia agrupar vários itens iguais ,preferencialmente por um campo (no caso Marcas_id)?

Comment: Você postou apenas o resultado de sua query com grupo e inner join não tem como entender a pergunta ficou confuso, poste a estrutura das duas tabelas. Talvez eu consiga ajudar!

Comment: Exatamente isso que quero,mostrar todas as concessionárias,mas mostrar preferencialmente as Concessionárias que tem o mesmo modelo do cliente.Do jeito que está agora,ele agrupa e ordena,porém ao ordenar,ele ordena errado pois o Marcas_id que ele pegou não é o valor do modelo do cliente,ai acaba afetando a ordem da lista.Como eu resolveria com o WHERE?

Comment: eu removi para olhar umas queries minhas aqui, já respondo novamente

Comment: Sim você quer todos os registros mas ordenado pela marca do cliente na frente correto ?

Comment: Isso,Exatamente !

Comment: Fui lá olhar uma querie que tenho algo parecido, no entanto gera duas queries distintas no meu código para fazer. O que eu conheço e poderia te ajudar é o comando ORDER BY FIELD(Marcas_id, 31,21,6,12); que fornece a ordenação mas para usa-lo teria que ter uma outra querie antes pegando as ids para utilizar dentro do comando.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar o código?,vai que resolve o meu problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70729/discussion-between-rafael-salomao-and-saidmrn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que encontramos foi fazer uma subquery utilizando o **INNER JOIN**  filtrando pelo id do estado e agrupando pelo campo **marcas_id** e em seguida ordenando a tabela temporaria por **marcas_id** na querie externa agrupamos por pelo id da concessionaria e novamente ordenamos pelo atributo marcas_id

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM concessionarias C inner join 
concessionarias_marcas CM on 
C.id = CM.Concessionarias_id and C.Estados_id = 14 GROUP BY Marcas_id  order 
by (Marcas_id = 31) DESC) AS CCM GROUP BY id order by  (CCM.Marcas_id = 31) 
DESC;
```

Créditos a saidmm por colaboração na solução do problema

Comment: Valeu ! Se não fosse por Você passaria o natal na frente do PC.